# Convexity of root

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

I need some help proving that
$$
\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x},
$$
with $\Sigma$ being a positive definite matrix, is convex. I already found some questions about this topic, indicating that one should use a conic representation but I did not understand these approaches, I was hoping maybe someone has another idea or could explain it better (maybe with a link to a resp. paper or book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $\Sigma\succeq 0$ then we can define $\sqrt{\mathbf{x}\Sigma\mathbf{x}}=\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\Sigma}$ to get a *normed vector space*, which has all the properties of the Euclidean norm. Specifically, it is absolutely homogeneous and the triangle inequality holds. Then the solution becomes very easy:
\begin{aligned}
f(\lambda\mathbf{x}+(1-\lambda)\mathbf{y})&=\|\lambda\mathbf{x}+(1-\lambda)\mathbf{y}\|_{\Sigma}\\&\leq \|\lambda\mathbf{x}\|_{\Sigma}+\|(1-\lambda)\mathbf{y}\|_{\Sigma}\\
&=|\lambda|\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\Sigma}+|(1-\lambda)|\|\mathbf{y}\|_{\Sigma}\\
&=\lambda f(\mathbf{x})+(1-\lambda)f(\mathbf{y}) &\square
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to prove this:

1. $(x,y) \mapsto x^\top \Sigma \, y$ is a scalar product and your function is the corresponding norm.
2. You have $\sqrt{x^\top \Sigma x} = \| \Sigma^{1/2} x\|$, i.e., the combination of a convex function and a linear function.